# Para assinaturas, devemos usar atentamente ou atenciosamente?

Tags: significado, linguagem

Em muitos e-mails ou cartas vejo com frequência as assinaturas "**Atentamente**" ou "**Atenciosamente**".

Qual a diferença entre elas?
Qual delas é a correta?

Answer (score 3):

**Atentamente** e **atenciosamente** são derivadas da palavra atenção (atencioso) e as duas tem o mesmo significado.

Tanto que se você procurar atentamente no dicionário ele traz o seguinte:

> **Atentamente**
>
> *Advérbio*
>
> 1. de modo atento; com atenção e interesse.
> 2. m.q. ATENCIOSAMENTE (fórmula de cortesia).